# How can I tell what server an old version of Redmine is running on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, ubuntu-10.04

I have an old install of Redmine sitting on an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server. I know the path to where the Redmine install is, at `/srv/www/redmine`, but not much more.

Because I didn't set it up, I don't really know what server platform it is running on, although one of the log file errors leads me to believe it might be nginx, but word of mouth suggests it might be running on mongrel.

**Where should I be looking / how can I find out what webserver the Redmine install is running on?**

I've tried commands like 
`mongral_rails`, `which apache`, `which nginx` and every other variation I can think of, but I'm not terribly familiar with ruby, so they're all just shots in the dark.

Comment: Have you tried using `netstat` to see which service is listening on the port via which you access redmine via HTTP …?

Comment: Yep, that's what lead me to the redmine install path. :/

Comment: Well what’s left to figure out then – if you know what web server service it is …?

Comment: the path that showed on netstat was to the ruby app, nginx was at a completely different location on the drive. Fixed now, anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this possible dirs if you can find the files to find out:

For Apache:

- `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`  And look for your `/srv/www/redmine/public`

For Nginx

- `/etc/nginx/conf.d` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` or `/opt/nginx/conf/conf.d` or something like that

That would do it under any standard setup, but you know every master has its own recipes.

If the app is up and running, another easy option if there is no complex situation to find out which services are running '**ps aux**', do it while browsing the app.

Comment: `ps aux` did the job. Apparently I am running nginx. I'd tried using `top` to spot the server process, but it must have flashed away too fast for me to see. You're a hero!